# d3 plugin installation issue in iPython

Tags: d3.js, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I found this question: 
http://grokbase.com/t/scipy.org/ipython-dev/12bygp3793/try-jsplugins-d3graph. 
In the solution is suggested compiling ipython from:
https://github.com/ellisonbg/ipython/tree/jsonhandlers

I did that and followed the directions here:
https://github.com/ipython/jsplugins

To summarize:
 I followed the instruction from 
and jsplugins > d3graph > README.md

d3graph.py : copied to .ipython\extensions

d3graph.js and d3graph.css : copied to 
.ipython\profile_default\static\jsplugins\d3graph

(Note: I am on ubuntu/linux 12.10
ipython-0.14.dev.egg-info)

run ipython notebook --pylab inline

open Visualizing Graphs with d3.ipynb

each cell was executed, but the graph did not show up.

But I can plot graph with:

```
pos=nx.spring_layout(G,iterations=100)
plt.subplot(221)
nx.draw(G,pos,font_size=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is very strange because I can`t to use the plugin too.

can you probe to do the instructions in the .config/.ipython/profile_default folder?. because that is the real sesion path